# Error Pushing node app to heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I keep getting this error when i try pushing to heroku, i have no idea what it means.

`error: unable to rewind rpc post data - try increasing http.postBuffer
error: fatal: WRPC failed; curl 56 SSL read: error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac, errno 0
The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (5327/5327), 44.34 MiB | 4.39 MiB/s, done.
Total 5327 (delta 1360), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date`

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```